# Crypto Obfuscator - how exclude xaml files?

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms, obfuscation, crypto-obfuscator

I created Xamarin Forms app for Android. I use .net standard library. This is shared library with my xaml views. I try use Crypto Obfuscator for obfuscation this library. But I get warnings(after obfuscate):

```
 In method <InitializeComponent>_anonXamlCDataTemplate_7.LoadDataTemplate(), Call To: System.Type.GetProperty(String )
```

These warnings are many. I found problems in the application after obfuscation.
Now I want to exclude xaml files from the obfuscation.

Example:

```
MyPage.xaml [not need obfuscation]

MyPage.xaml.cs [need obfuscation]
```

I read article about Exclusion/Inclusion Rules Tab for Crypt Obfuscation. But I did not find how to solve my question.

Is this possible? Any ideas? Or do I need another tool?

Comment: But if you obfuscate method names in xaml.cs and use those in your xaml, wouldn't that break also?

Comment: Hi  Cheesebaron, I can use option "Bundle assemblies into native code" .Will it protect my code or not? If yes -than obfuscation is not needed